# Creating a Dynamic Calculation of Pandas Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

I am trying to loop through each row within a pandas dataframe.  Turning each value in the current row into a float.  If there are any blanks in the data within that row, I want to skip that row.  However, if there are no blanks in the row, I want to run a calculation on the data from cells within that row to ultimately return whether the calculation on the data from that row is TRUE or FALSE for that specific row. Then it would go to the next row through the end of the dataframe.

Each time I run the function, the calculation to be run through the dataframe will be different.

### PLEASE NOTE: I can perform this inline, but I would like to create a function to limit the lines of code within my main file.

This is a simplified example of the function I tried to build to perform this task along with the returned error below...

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'prod_code': ['1', '2', '3', '', '5'],
     'timestamp': ['1672700400', '1672700460', '1672700520', '1672700580', '1672700640'],
     'cost': [43, 45, 46, 41, 48]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)


def calculation(dataframe, *columns_and_calc):
    data = []
    for index, row in dataframe[columns_and_calc[:-1]].iterrows():
        try:
            row = row.astype(float)
        except ValueError:
            data.append("")
        else:
            if columns_and_calc[-1]:
                data.append(True)
            else:
                data.append(False)


calculation(df, 'timestamp', 'cost', row['cost'] == 43)
```

> **ERROR MESSAGE** = "NameError: name 'row' is not defined. Did you mean: 'pow'?"

### FOR REFERENCE here is how I am running the code inline that is currently working.

```
visibleShort = False 
for index, row in dataFile_1min.data[['close', 'leadline_1', 'leadline_2', 'cu1', 'cu2', 'timestamp']].iterrows():
    # visibleShort = False 
    try:
        row = row.astype(float)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        if (row['close'] < row['leadline_1'] and row['close'] < row['leadline_2']) and (row['cu1'] or row['cu2']) and row['timestamp'] != dataFile_1min.data['timestamp'].iloc[-1]: 
            visibleShort = True
    print(visibleShort)
```

Comment: The error is from your `row['cost'] == 43` argument. You haven't defined what `row` is there and also, I'm not sure why you are passing a boolean statement.

Comment: I want to have a function that I can pass a conditional statement into that will output whether that conditional statement is true or false.